# Not prompting for input (Python/Jupyter/Chrome)

Tags: python, function, jupyter-notebook, user-input, restart

Part 1:

```
"""" Return full name"""
def get_formatted_name(first,last):
     full_name = f"{first} {last}"
     return full_name
```

Part 2:

```
while True:
    print("\n Please enter your name")
    print("(enter 'q' at any time to quit)")
    
    f_name = input("First name: ")
    if f_name == 'q':
        break
    
    l_name = input("Last name: ")
    if l_name == 'q':
        break
    
    formatted_name = get_formatted_name(f_name,l_name)
    print(f"\nHello, {formatted_name}!")   

print("Function excercise completed")
```

I am using Jupyter notebook in Chrome and wrote the above code. If I compile Part 1 in a different cell and try to execute Part 2, it won't even prompt for the input. Once it doesn't prompt for the input, even if I execute both Part 1 & Part 2 in the same cell, it won't prompt for the input. However, if I restart Jupyter Notebook, the code works as usual.

What's it making not to prompt for input if I don't have Part 1 in the same cell as Part 2 in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Please fix your code to be in a code block It is not readable as is.

Comment: Added a pic, thank you!